# Reading data from an html table input tag in R

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to read a HTML-table from an internal webpage into R.

Unfortunately for me, the `<td>`'s have a weird structure, so I can't use `html_table()` from the `rvest` package to do this for me.

The structure for the html table is as follows:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input disabled name="Attribute A" value="15.00">
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This then repeats with multiple `<td>`'s per row. I'd like to extract the value for each entry, I'm just a bit unsure how.

I've been thinking about writing a parser that throws the contents of every `<td>` into the corresponding column and then using regex to match the `name="Attribute A"` and return the value. However, this seems very convoluted and I'm hoping there's a more efficient option :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was:

```
vars = c("name", "value") #Define attributes you want to keep

file.Read <- read_html(file)

file.Read %>% 
   html_nodes(xpath = '//input') %>%
   html_attrs() %>%
   lapply(function(x) {unlist(x[vars])})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps for a start:

```
your_url <- read_html(url)
html_nodes(your_url, xpath = '//input') %>% html_attr('name')
```

Or more general:

```
your_url <- read_html(url)

#option 1
html_nodes(your_url, xpath = '//td') %>%
  html_text() 
    
#option 2
html_nodes(your_url, xpath = '//table//tr') %>%
  html_text()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. 'html_text()' didnt return the text within the tags.

What I ended up doing was:
'''
file.Read <- read_html(file)

file.Read %>% 
   html_nodes(xpath = '//input') %>%
   html_attrs()